# BZIP2 Compress file lags

Tags: linux, centos, server, admin, bzip2

I am experiencing a problem, when i use Bzip2 to compress files. I feel causses  lags on my CS:GO(application) server.

**Example of command:**

```
bzip2 -kqs --fast mg_runordie_final.bsp
```

Once the commend runs I notice an increase in application lag.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to detect what is causing my application to lag?

System info:

- CentOS 6.5
- CPU 3.4Ghz
- 1024RAM
- SAS+HDD Cache

So i dont think that the problem is in my hardware, it seems to be a software problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in system priority.

```
nice -20 bzip2 mg_runordie_final.bsp
```

solved.